# Check whether password and re-entered password are same or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html signup form in which I want to check whether password and re-entered password are same or not in Javascript.
Here is the code :

```js
< script >
  function pass() {
    var pas = document.getElementById("pass");
    var rpas = document.getElementById("rpass");
    if (pas.value != rpas.value) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter same password in Retype Password..";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    }
  }


  <
  /script>
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div id="signup" class="tab-content show">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="ReType Password" name="rpass" id="rpass" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" id="gender" checked="checked" />Male
    <input type="radio" value="FeMale" name="gender" id="gender" />Female
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="pass()" />
    <p id="error"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Problem is that Javascript is not working..

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem/question and not be the exact same as the "question". Proper and consistent indentation makes code so much more readable. _"problem is that javascript is not working..."_ is not a sufficient explanation of the problem. What does not work? What happens? What isn't happening? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are submitting the form there. You have used onClick event on submit button, but when submit button is pressed form is submitted and you can call a function in the form tag in onSubmit attribute and then you have to stop form submission otherwise the form will be submitted and the page will reload

Comment: It would be a much better answer if you'd share a working code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change input type "submit" to input type="button".

```js
<script >
function pass(){
 var pas = document.getElementById("pass");
 var rpas = document.getElementById("rpass"); 
if (pas.value != rpas.value){
 document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Enter same password in Retype Password..";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="";
  }
}
 

</script>
```

```html
<form action="">
<div id="signup" class="tab-content show">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="password" placeholder="ReType Password" name="rpass" id="rpass" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" id="gender" checked="checked"/>Male
<input type="radio" value="FeMale" name="gender" id="gender" />Female
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="pass()" />
<p id="error"></p>
 </div>
 </form>
```

You can check below code on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

    <form action="">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      Password:<br>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="pswd">
      <br><br>
      Re-Password:<br>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="rpswd">
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pass()">
    </form>

    <p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

    <script>
      function pass() {
        var paswd = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        var rpswd = document.getElementById("rpswd").value;

        alert(paswd !== rpswd);
      }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Also you can follow the answer of whis san

Comment: If you're using a code snippet then please hit the "Tidy" button/link before saving the snippet.